# Solving C question possibly requiring while loop

Tags: c

I have this C question:

"Write a program that reads a positive integer x and displays the maximum positive
integer n for which the sum 1^2 + 2^2+ 3^2+ …+ n^2 is less than the given number."

From what I understand, I have to print the value of n. I tried using a while loop to find the sum of numbers before x is reached, but my code isn't working properly. Any help? Thanks!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
//while and for loop?
    int a = 90, n = 1;
    float sum;
    while(sum<a){
        sum += pow(n,2);
        n++;
    }
    printf("%d", n);
    
}
```

Comment: What is the initial value of `sum`? Uninitialized local variables really *are* uninitialized, and will have an *indeterminate* value (look at it as garbage).

Comment: Also don't use the floating-point `pow` function family for integer powers. Especially not for powers of `2` which can be handled with bit-shifting.

Comment: Plus, once solved the 2 errors outlined by @Someprogrammerdude your algorithm will show the smallest n for which Σ₁..ₙ k² is ≥ a, not the maximum n for which it is < a

Comment: To develop code, you have to be motivated to do more than type a few lines, then turn to someone else to fill in the rest. Demonstrate some effort and ask for help when you really are stuck. There are other career paths.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There is no power of 2, but a square. However, this can also be replace by simple integer arithmetic.

Comment: @thebusybee Ah yes, misread. So just plain single multiplication, almost even simpler.